# Проверка форм GET

Tags: php, get

Добрый день. Не могу понять как правильно проверить форму в php.

```
<!-- Область основного контента -->
<form action='calc.php' method="get">
  <label>Число 1:</label>
  <br />
  <input name='num1' type='text' />
  <br />
  <label>Оператор: </label>
  <br />
  <input name='operator' type='text' />
  <br />
  <label>Число 2: </label>
  <br />
  <input name='num2' type='text' />
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type='submit' value='Считать'>
</form>
<!-- Область основного контента -->

 <?php
    // var_dump($_GET);

   if (empty($_GET)){
      return 'Ничего не передано!';
    }

    if (empty($_GET['num1'])|| empty($_GET['num2'])) {
      return 'Не переданы аргументы!';
    }

    if (empty($_GET['operator'])) {
       return 'Не передана операция';
    }

 ?>
```

Интересуют такие вопросы:
1)Можно возвращать результат через return или же писать через echo?
2) Когда писал через echo вторая и третья проверки срабатывали, а вот 1 никогда не работала...

Comment: returt можно использовать, если вы напишите функции проверки, и уже при ее выполнении использовать echo. Или при использовании ajax. А так я бы посоветовал использовать `method="post"` т.к. get захломит вам search bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) echo так как PHP скрипт выполняется на стороне сервера, а пользователь отправив запрос видит результат этого скрипта

2) Ну так как вы отправляли GET через форму, а GET массив, то он выглядел примерно так: (Array (2) => "name"=>"","num2"=>"")

Comment: а почему не отрабатывают строки _if (empty($_GET)){
      echo 'Ничего не передано!';
    }_ ???

Comment: @White_Snow напишите в начале скрипта var_dump($_GET) и скиньте результат, если не поняли в чем прикол :)

Comment: _array(3) { ["num1"]=> string(0) "" ["operator"]=> string(0) "" ["num2"]=> string(0) "" }_  Ну массив же пустой

Comment: @White_Snow, нет :) Под элементы массивы пустые, а сам Массив имеет значения num1 operator num2, целых 3!!! так что он не пустой

Comment: @White_Snow, кстати var_dump вам вывел размерность массива array(3) т е 3